# Why doesn't the installer see all of my hard drives?

Tags: system-installation, ubiquity

I'm trying to setup a dual boot system with Windows Vista 64 (already installed) and Ubuntu 10.10. I added a new drive which is identical to the one Vista is installed on. When I boot into the LiveCD I can see and mount the second drive and edit it in Gparted. However, when I use the installer it will only bring up the drive that already has Vista installed.

I've tried everything I know. I'm not sure if its a BIOS setting or something else I've missed.

I've also tried both the desktop and alternate amd64 installs with the same result.

Comment: Did you choose manual partitioning?

Comment: Yes, it is in manual partitioning where I do not see it. Also get the same results in the other two install options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to boot a live session and start a terminal session (or to switch to the console with CTRL-ALT-F1) and issue:

```
sudo os-prober
```

You'll probably see a probing error which could be the reason why your drive is not taken in consideration. It's quite likely that your second drive has leftovers of a RAID configuration, in this case it's sufficient to do:

```
sudo dmraid -rE
```

(-r = raid, -E remove metadata) and confirm the operation. Start the installer and you should see it.

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get remove dmraid

This seems to have fixed the problem for me. At least now I'm not getting the empty drive box. It's asking me to choose from 3 options.

Answer (score 0):

- check with

  ```
  cat /proc/partitions
  ```

to see which partition is the new one (the size can give you a clue)

- Create some dir to mount the disk
- Add a line in /etc/fstab accordingly

Run

```
 sudo mount -a
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the alternative installer iso? It is a hassle to use, but gives you much more control over the installation process.

This is just a hunch, I am not sure it will solve the problem. It requires an additional CD-sized download and about half an hour of answering prompts about things the graphical installer discovers automatically, so only try it if the easier methods have failed.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a somewhat-similar installation issue when I was attempting to install Kubuntu 10.4 on a computer with Windows 7 installed.  With the issue, I only had one hard drive, but it just wasn't showing in the partition list, even after I partitioned a good chunk off for the install.

The eventual solution revolved around the fact that the live cd had dmraid installed by default.

I live-booted into terminal, entered `sudo apt-get remove dmraid` and my issue was fixed.  Hope it works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I had a partition type of GPD (had Windows 10 on the drive prior), to get around this I used fdisk to create a new 'dos' label.

In this day and age I'm amazed that the install doesn't account for this (and support GPD)

Hope this helps.