# Installing Ubuntu on a SATA drive

Tags: hardware, installation, sata

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 10.04 on a SATA drive on a desktop computer. It's a 2 TB hitachi. If I go through the standard install process, I get an fsync error. The drive showed up in the installer. When I swapped to the terminal and did an `fdisk -l`, it showed the other drives, but instead of sda, I got another error message that was also in `dmesg`:

```
[  243.128549] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 3907029152
[  243.128648] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled error code
[  243.128652] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  243.128656] sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 e8 e0 87 20 00 00 08 00
```

dmesg had about 250 copies of those four lines.

I checked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44550/problem-installing-ubuntu-11-04-on-computer-with-sata-harddrive), and even checked the BIOS settings, but I couldn't find anything helpful, so I turn to the mighty collective wisdom of the SE network. Any ideas about what's wrong? Need more info?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you check drive for hardware defects with [Hitachi Drive Fitness Test](http://www.hitachigst.com/support/downloads/), check cables etc.. Is this a new drive? What was on it before, how was it formatted? What BIOS settings did you try?

Comment: It's a brand new drive. I'm suspecting something rather than the drive, since I have another drive that also had the same error. I'll get the BIOS info up this morning or this evening.

Comment: Might be a bad cable.  did you try using a different one?

Comment: DID_BAD_TARGET means there is no such drive.  Look for an earlier error that might have led to the drive going away.  It should mention ata.

Comment: I swapped out the cable, still no dice. Turns out that booting from the USB caused the problems. Currently it's installing from a CD. Any clues why that would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the problem was that I was trying to install off of a USB stick. I'm guessing that there was some problem with `/dev/sda` when the installer booted off of `/dev/sdb`.

My only guess is that there's some conflict between the serial-ness of the two. I burned a CD (had to use the USB to do that since my other computer has no optical drives!) and it's installing just fine!