# I am having problems booting after I installed Ubuntu. How can I collect information to diagnose and fix the problem?

Tags: boot, grub2, boot-failure, grub-efi

After installing or updating Ubuntu, I am having problems using GRUB to boot my computer. How do I collect information to determine what is wrong so that I can fix it?

- **Note:** This question and any answers to it is an attempt to publicly document a [**canonical answer**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) as suggested in this [**Stack Exchange BLOG post**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/).

Answer (score 4):

#### Using the `boot-repair` utility to create a BootInfo summary

The [**Boot-Repair**](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) utility is an easy to use tool which can help diagnose and repair  boot issues in Ubuntu. In particular, it can be used to easily create a [*BootInfo summary*](http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/) and share it as a pastebin on http://paste.ubuntu.com to help diagnose an Ubuntu boot issue.

**Note:** The example images used below are from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS desktop.

1. Start Ubuntu and, if necessary, login to display the Ubuntu desktop.

   **Note:** If you cannot boot Ubuntu from your computer's  hard
   drive, then boot from an [*Ubuntu Live CD* (or *USB*)](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) and select `Try
   Ubuntu`.
2. You will need to be connected to the Internet for the steps below to
   work. If your network is not connected, then try enabling it by
   clicking on the connection in the menu of the *Network Indicator*.
   **Note:** The *Network Indicator* icon is in the upper right-hand of the
   desktop. (See example below.)

   [image: picture of networking indicator menu]
3. Open a terminal (command prompt) window.
   **Note:** You should be able to use the keyboard shortcut 
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to do this.
4. Enter the commands below one at a time into the terminal window. These commands use the system tool `apt-get` to install the `boot-repair` utility.

   > ```
   > sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   > sudo apt-get update
   > sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
   > ```
   >
   > **Note:** If you display this answer in a browser window, then you can copy the text of a command into the clipboard and then paste it into the terminal. The keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> should paste the content of the clipboard into the terminal window.
5. After the commands above have completed, enter the command `boot-repair` to start the utility.
6. After a slight delay, `boot-repair` will prompt you to download the
   newest version. Since you just installed the latest version, answer
   `No`.
7. **Important:** If `boot-repair` asks to install the `pastebinit` package, respond with **`Yes`**.
8. `boot-repair` will now scan your computer and then will display the window shown in the example below. Click on the <kbd>Create a Bootinfo summary</kbd> box/button. This will collect information about your computer's boot configuration. *This will only **collect** information. No changes will be made to your computer's boot configuration.*

   [image: screenshot of main Boot-Repair Window]
9. After the Bootinfo summary has been created, `boot-repair` will display a message containing a URL. The message will look like the example below. The URL in the example is `http://paste.ubuntu.com/943841/`. 

   [image: screenshot of boot-repair's completion message]

   **Important:** Please add this URL to your question. The information in the pastebin this link points to will help us to understand what is happening on your computer.

   **Note:** You can use the `edit` link (see screenshot below) to update/edit your question to add the URL to it.

   [image: screenshot of edit link for a question]

Answer (score 0):

Variant: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11136267&postcount=1