# What did I do wrong installing Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, live-cd

I just attempted to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my other computer. I downloaded the .iso file, burned it to a disc, and booted from it. Before I continue, I might add that I already have an OS on this computer (Windows 7) and was attempting to install Ubuntu alongside it.

So, I selected my language, and clicked "Install Ubuntu" when the screen popped up. The window changed and said that I didn't have any operating system installed, what did I want to do? It gave me the option to wipe the disk and install Ubuntu, or "something else." I clicked "something else" and setup two partitions on my hard disk for Ubuntu, one for the system files and one for the swap area. These two partitions were created in Win7. I just changed the file systems and mounted one of them with "/."

Then I clicked install, everything was going well, and then it said I had to restart my computer to use Ubuntu. So I restarted, and then the Windows logo appeared for a second, then it started the startup repair tool. So, I went through that, then restarted again. After the second restart, a screen popped up (purple background, like Ubuntu when it's loading) and there were a bunch of operating systems available. I chose Ubuntu, and it loaded fine. So then I restarted and tried to start Windows. It said there was a problem with Windows and that I needed to insert my installation media.

So I restarted (pressed the power button). The BIOS loaded, then it was just a blank screen with a gray cursor like a cmd box in Windows, except there was no text. Nothing will load. What did I do wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "These two partitions were created in Win7" in what format were these partitions? NTFS?

Comment: Would you please create and post the link to a BootInfo summary for your computer by following the steps described in this question: [*I am having problems booting after I installed Ubuntu. How can I collect information to diagnose and fix the problem?*](http://askubuntu.com/q/150093/52923)

Comment: Yes, they are NTFS. I can't get the boot info, because I restored my computer to the factory state already. Is there any way to figure out what I did wrong without the boot info?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you installed Ubuntu by mistake over Windows, while keeping the windows MBR (master boot record) information. I'd recommend these two options:

- If you want to run only Ubuntu, put Ubuntu on a USB stick/CD and boot from that. Then choose to wipe your hard drive entirely and run only Ubuntu.
- If you want to run Windows and Ubuntu side by side, I recommend you first of all reinstall Windows completely. You can do this if you have a restore CD or restore partition that still works. When Windows is back, do not install Ubuntu from a CD/USB, install it from within Windows with a tool called "[Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer)".