# Why cannot Ubuntu 12.04 detect windows 7 (dual boot)

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7, system-installation

I was trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside with windows 7. I only have one hard drive (1TB), and I first installed window 7 on one partition. Now there are about 500GB unlocated space on the disk, and I'd like to install Ubuntu on that part of that partition.

What I did was to boot from a usb stick to install Ubuntu. I have the same problem with the following post.

[Ubuntu 12.04 installer does not see Windows already installed on my computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141656/ubuntu-12-04-does-not-see-windows-already-install-on-my-computer-dual-installat)

In the installation, Ubuntu cannot detect the windows 7, so there is no option "install ubuntu alongside with windows 7". I follow the suggestion provided in the above post, and installed the "boot-repair" tool. Then I use the boot-repair tool to create a Bootinfo summary.

Thu url of the bootinfo: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1057933/

I also use "try ubuntu" to use the terminal.
When I type "sudo os-prober" in the command line, it returns nothing. It seems that ubuntu cannot detect the installed windows 7.

Since my situation is different from that in the previous post. I only have one hard drive, so the problem should not be related to any raid thing.

Can anybody help me on this? What can I to make ubuntu to detect the windows 7.

Comment: Why don't you try custom installation by defining Ubuntu's partitions manually  .After installation completes , i am pretty sure it will be sorted out .If not then run `sudo update-grub` from installed Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Problem solved. I use the "boot-repair" tool, and choose "recommended repair". After it finishes everything, I reboot my computer and try to install ubuntu again. The option "install ubuntu alongside with windows 7" is there. Bingo!

Comment: Fine , post this as your answer and accept it. So others having having same problems can sort out.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that I have to wait for 10 hours to answer the question since I am new.

Comment: New problem appears. After the installation, if I select to boot windows 7, it can not start....... eh! It says there is some error and I need to repair the windows. Maybe it is because that I choose the "recommended repair" of the boot-repair tool?

Comment: Does it boot normally even if it shows repair option. I guess its fine , windows does panic at such manual boot repair.

Comment: I've been having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your PC uses a recent boot system (EFI), which may be why GRUB (which uses os-prober) did not detect Windows. This is a bug of os-prober that should be reported [here](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?package=os-prober).
2. Repair your Windows boot by booting on a Seven Recovery CD ([32bit](http://freakshare.com/files/o2db6v0s/CyberNetNews.com_Windows_7_32-bit_Repair_Disc.iso.html) or [64bit](http://freakshare.com/files/56apzmkl/CyberNetNews.com_Windows_7_64-bit_Repair_Disc.iso.html)), then type these 2 commands:

   bootrec /fixmbr

   bootrec /fixboot
3. When you recovered direct access to Windows, use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to recover the GRUB menu