# How can I dual-boot with Windows 7 if the installer does not detect it?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-7

I want to install Ubuntu, but keep my Windows 7 partition.

Do you have any ideas?

You can look at my screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @DavidFoerster That question doesn't really address this particular issue.

Comment: There are [many](http://askubuntu.com/q/360788/18612) [questions](http://askubuntu.com/q/185116/18612) [asked](http://askubuntu.com/q/155492/18612) about this particular topic already, but unfortunately I cannot find one with an accepted answer to mark this duplicate of. You might be best off [filing a bug report against Ubiquity](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+filebug).

Answer (score -1):

I know a very simple and time saving trick for this. You will need a small amazing os called puppy linux for this operation. It's a small os about 200mb designed to run from cd's only. With this method you'll save several minutes and alot of energy. First install the Ubuntu using the something else method. After that, you're pc will boot straight into ubuntu without detecting windows at all. The remove the Ubuntu bootable cd and put in the precise puppy cd. When puppy boots, go to the menu and look for grub dos or something like that name. I don't remember the exact name but usually there's two grub one with dos name and the other with legacy name, so choose the one with dos. Use the grub software to set up a dual boot menu. It automatically detects all the operating systems that you have in your hard drives, takes a few seconds or minutes to do that and after installing the dual boot, you can customize it by editing the menu via the text. Just copy paste the text of the oses where you want each to arrange. For example if you want the windows to be the first one, when you start grub installer select single menu list and then after it open the menu text, just copy the text for windows and paste it at the first line before the other os. This is a very simple process. I hope you understand my english. I'm not good english dude.

Comment: Please explain how to install Ubuntu with the “something else” option (see [How to write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer)). Beyond that I don't understand why one would need to fiddle with the boot loader so much or why Puppy Linux is necessary. If the boot configuration actually is broken after installation, why not simply use the Ubuntu live system that performed the installation and run `boot-repair`?