# While installing Ubuntu from Ubuntu Desktop (from USB)

Tags: 12.04, installation, partitioning, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu 12.04 does not see windows already install on my computer (dual installation)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141656/ubuntu-12-04-does-not-see-windows-already-install-on-my-computer-dual-installat)

I downloaded the Ubuntu Software to create a USB to install Ubuntu. I rebooted my PC (Windows 7), in wich i did a partition (:E) just for Ubuntu. But when i start the installer, it says there's no other OS in my computer, and doesn't give me the option to install it in :E, just the option to format the WHOLE hard drive and install it there. What can i do?

User68186 told me to type "sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda" in the ubuntu terminal but it says: "no raid disks with names: "/dev/sda"". I opened GParted, and in /dev/sda (465.76GiB) it says: partition: unallocated; file system: unallocated; size: 465.76GiB. This is what I did: [Only 'sdb' shows up when installing 12.04 on a new Dell inspiron 14z](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190689/only-sdb-shows-up-when-installing-12-04-on-a-new-dell-inspiron-14z/190698#190698) .

Also, i tried Wubi before, but it had an error with "wubildr.mbr"

Comment: Also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/148648/ubiquity-is-not-recognizing-existing-partition-while-trying-to-install-ubuntu-al