# Ubiquity doesn't see any partitions on the Disk

Tags: installation, boot, 12.10, dual-boot, windows-7

I want to install Xubuntu 12.10 on a system which has already Windows 7 on it. However, the Ubiquity installation program does not recognize any partitions on the system and shows it to me as empty. But `fdisk` and `/dev` list the partitions to me, and I can mount them manually.

From [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141656/ubuntu-12-04-does-not-see-windows-already-install-on-my-computer-dual-installat) question I tried the provided solutions, but neither the `dmraid -rE` command nor running the ubiquity via `sudo` helped here. According to the last recommendation, I used `boot-repair` to sum up the trouble, and the paste can be found [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1407746/). Obviously, `os-prober` does see the Windows installation, just `ubiquity` doesn't.

I'd be very thankful for a quick help, I need the dual-boot system for work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After about three hours, I found out that the Windows 7 installer had originally written the partitions bigger than the harddisk claimed to be. Thus the `libparted` of Ubiquity thought the partition table was corrupted.

The solution was quite simple: Just shrink the windows partition to the desired size and leave the rest of the disk empty. `fdisk` can read the oversized partition table just fine.

Afterwards use Ubiquity like normal to create the necessary partitions on the empty space - `libparted` will make sure they're the size of the harddisk.