# Preinstalled Windows 8 Not showing up on Grub 2, Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, grub2, dual-boot, windows-8, boot-repair

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1522276/

Hi There, I've scoured everywhere & I'm still all very confused.
Since I'm a total noob, I don't really want to touch too many files...

I have an Acer M5 with Windows 8 preinstalled.
I installed Ubuntu 12.10 in secure boot, but Grub does not recognize my Windows 8.
I tried boot-repair, to no avail.

Here are my specs: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1522276/

Please help?

Answer (score 0):

Launch a terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T and type
`sudo os-prober` and check if it detects your windows 8.
IF it detects windows 8 then do `sudo update-grub`.

To install os prober do `sudo apt-get install os-prober`

Comment: hi, i launched my terminal & installed & ran os-prober, it didn't show anything, or load anything...

Comment: Then most probably you have accidentally deleted Windows 8 while installing Ubuntu.
You might want to try http://www.supergrubdisk.org/ to check if it detects windows 8. You have to burn it to usb pen drive or CD. Use dd command in terminal `dd if=/path/to/isofile/supergrubdisk.iso of=/dev/Xda` where X is the name of your pen drive. Use `fdisk -l` to know name of your pen drive.

Comment: if you look at my boot sequence here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1522276/  - i believe my Windows 8 lives in /sda4 - so I don't believe i deleted it, since i created a partition specifically for Ubuntu before installing, i just don't think my Grub is reading my Windows...

Comment: See if this thread helps you http://askubuntu.com/questions/141656/ubuntu-12-04-does-not-see-windows-already-install-on-my-computer-dual-installat

Comment: Hi Abhijit, thanks for the link but I don't think this is helpig me, since I am not loading Windows 7 or 12.04 - in fact, my Windows 7 machine is successfully dual booted... may you be able to clarify maybe what I should be looking at? the os-prober part? boot-repair printed out my boot sequence here http://paste.ubuntu.com/1522276/ - i believe my next step is to configure Grub accordingly to my specs.

Comment: Have you followed that question completely? Though you are not using windows 7 it do not make a 'great' difference. It does make a difference but not significant. You can still follow that post to resolve your windows 8 issue.

Comment: I had similar problem with win 7 because I installed UBUNTU in UEFI, but WIN 7 was on legacy. I inserted win 7 OS installation disk, booted from it, selected repair, opend up command prompt and typed "bootrec /fixmbr" and then "bootrec /fixboot". This made win 7 load properly, but GRUB was removed, Then I installed UBUNTU in legacy mode too, then everything went fine

Comment: @GauravSharma You might want to write this as a separate answer with all the detailed steps rather than writing it as just a comment here.