# Can't remove RAID metadata from Dell R710 disks

Tags: server, raid

I've been trying hard to disable Dell R710 RAID mechanism to install Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS on the server but I couldn't so far.

Based on [this question's answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21267/why-doesnt-the-installer-see-all-of-my-hard-drives), I should boot using a live cd (done using ubuntu desktop 11), but the mentioned commands shows unexpected responses.

`sudo os-prober`, returns nothing
`sudo dmraid -rE`, returns `no block devices found !`

Previously I deleted the 3 virtual disks and their controller, should I try to reconfigure them again ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R710 supports LSI-based PERC controllers utilizing the mpt2sas driver and should work just fine with Ubuntu. You'll need to create virtual disks for the controller to expose via the driver before Ubuntu can see them to install on them. Without an OS installed, the easiest way to do that is to press Ctrl+R when prompted during POST to get to the controller BIOS option ROM (most likely this is where you deleted the virtual disks in the first place!) If you have a PERC S100 or S300 controller unfortunately there is no Linux driver for it so you would not be able to use either of those at all. But any of the PERC H200, H700, or H800 should work just fine.