# Wubi Ubuntu Installation "No Root File System Defined"

Tags: wubi, files, root, system, installation

I Downloaded Wubi.exe & Ubuntu 12.04 LTS From The Official Website Then Put Them In A Single Folder In My Internal Hard Disk. Then I Run Wubi, And It Got Installed Within 2 Minutes. And Then I Rebooted My PC. Then Ubuntu Loaded Up And There Were No Icons Anywhere Just A Black Bar At The Top And The Ubuntu Default Background Wallpaper. Then A popup Came Up Saying Verifying Files And Then A Box Popped Up Saying "No Root File System Defined, Fix This In Partitioning Menu". I Tried To Close It But It Pops Up Again. And Im Stuck Here With Absolutely No Idea What To Do. Im Good At Windows But I Have Zero Experience Of Linux Ubuntu. I Need Help Desperately!

EDIT: I Tried "sudo parted -l" with lower case L. It Asked Me Whether It Was A GPT Table. I Said "No" Then Nothing Happened. But My Problem Still Isn't Solved.I Also Tried "sudo blkid" And It Told Me That My Hard Disk Partitions Are Of "NTFS" Type(Which I Already Know). Please Help Me.I Tried "sudo apt-get remove dmraid" But It Returned with a error code 1 And My Problem Wasn"t Solved.Installation & Un-installation Processes Take Less Than A Minute, Isn't It Fishy?

Comment: This can be caused by partition table problems or unsupported fakeraid. When you get that message, can you drop to a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and run `sudo parted -l` and check for any error message. Then `sudo reboot` restarts the machine. Report back. PS you might as well run `sudo blkid` as well

Comment: In One Of The Forums They Mentioned This "sudo apt-get remove dmraid". What Does It Do? Will It Help?

Comment: I don't know enough about raid to recommend this. Firstly it should only affect you if you have a fakeraid, and secondly, you should find someone who can explain what is going on rather than just try random commands. There does appear to be an issue with dmraid though: http://pad.lv/1054948

Comment: Assuming you do have fakeraid, this is a possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/21267/14916 I'd still advise you to run those commands I mentioned in the first comment and update your question before trying fixes that may or may not be applicable.

Comment: I Tried "sudo parted 1" but It Says "could not read, no such file or directory". I Tried "sudo apt-get remove dmraid" But It Returned with a error code 1 And My Problem Wasn"t Solved.PS I Did Not Reboot. The Installation & Un-installation Processes Take Less Than A Minute, Isn't It Fishy?

Comment: that's a lower case -L (-l) i.e. `sudo parted -l`

Comment: I Tried "sudo parted -l" with lower case L. It Asked Me Whether It Was A GPT Table. I Said Yes Then Something Happened But My Problem Still Isn't Solved.I Also Tried "sudo blkid" And It Told Me That My Hard Disk Partitions Are Of "NTFS" Type(Which I Already Know). Please Help Me.

Comment: Wubi doesn't work on gpt disks as far as I know. So try answering no. And what is 'Something Happened'? Also try running `sudo fdisk -l`. Take a picture if you don't want to type out what you see.

Comment: Ive Got A Mix Of GPT & MSdos Tables. sudo fdisk -l gave me a lot of info but how do I capture the screen?I mean how to take screenshot? My Friend Suggests That i Install Using Live CD But I Desperately Want To Use Wubi For Safe Install & Un-Install. Cuz I'll Be Keeping Windows 7.Please Help. :C

Comment: You need a camera. Or save the output: `sudo fdisk -l > /host/ubuntu/savefdisk.txt` (then you can open it from C:\ubuntu and use Wordpad, not Notepad) Installing from the live CD will have the same problem because they both use `ubiquity`, which uses `parted`. You could try installing Wubi using the `diskimage` (i.e. run standalone without `ISO`) because then it skips `ubiquity`. But the real answer is to follow that duplicate link and remove the conflicting GPT information. PS if you boot from an Ubuntu CD you can run the bootinfoscript and it will provide the information.

Comment: It Says Warning GPT Partition Table Found In sda1, It Does Not Support GPT. And "sudo fdisk -l > /host/ubuntu/savefdisk.txt" Did Not Work. Im Working On Other Of Your Solutions Please Stand By. If All Fails Then Ill Click A Photo With My Camera.

Comment: mmm probably it hasn't been able to mount the /host because of the problem. So take a photo, or run the bootinfoscript from the live CD, but if it looks like this: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1354965/ then you need fixparts to remove the GPT data.

Comment: It seems I need to use fixparts and yeah It looks similar to that. plz help me to use fixparts please. By the way , any idea where that GPT partition Table Might Have Come From

Comment: It can get there if the drive was previously used on a Mac. Converting to MBR partition table didn't erase all the GPT data. If you need help with `fixparts` first review all the information here http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/ and if anything is not clear, I would suggest creating a new question for the specific issue.

Comment: @bcbc Can this be answered? (Should it be closed?)